# What type of sound is this? How can I make something simmilar?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I am working on a game project and I began searching for sounds. I stumbled upon one that sounds really good to me and I want to create something similar. Any ideas how to do it?

The sound: http://vocaroo.com/i/s1zegHof9ope

Answer (score 1):

You need to start breaking the sound down into it's components and then work on sourcing similar sound components, layering them in a DAW and then mixing them. Start with trying to listen and describing the sound layers that you hear.

Comment: Is there a software I can use to create a sound like this?

Comment: any Digital Audio workstation will be a good starting point. - try Protools or Reaper

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me a lot like a synthesized pan flute with very fast attack and a bit of reverb.

Comment: Is there a software I can use to create a sound like this?

Comment: I have no personal experience with any of these but try...

https://www.google.com/search?q=daw+software+pan+flute+synthisizer&oq=daw+software+pan+flute+synthisizer&aqs=chrome..69i57.19669j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=daw+software+pan+flute+synthesizer